# Hide CRM form left hand side navigation item

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have my account entity linked to a custom entity called inspections, I only want these inspections to be created for accounts of a certain type. So when it isn't that type I want the left hand navigation to this entity to be hidden away. I've seen some code that says will hide it away, as long as you have the navID of the item.

I've had a crack at hiding it using what i thought could be the ID but it hasn't worked, so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to get this ID, or if there is another way to do this?

The code I'm using to hide the navigation is below:

```js
var navitem = Xrm.Page.ui.navigation.items.get("nav_ts_inspection"); 

    if (navitem != null)  
    {           
        navitem.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Load the form
- Press F12 to show IE Developer's Toolbar

From here you can use `CTRL+F` to search for the display name of the item you'd like to hide. This will give you `a` link that is generated. The Id of this element is what you need to use to show/hide the link.

As an example, you can see results of searching for 'Sub Accounts' on the Account screen for an installation I am working on at the moment. The Id can be seen and is 'navSubAct'

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, found out the id was nav_ts_account_inspection, so looks like it includes the related entity in its name too. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Changes by traversing DOM and manually hide an area is not officially supported.

Luckily if you are on CRM 2011, you can go to 
Settings > Customization Or open the solution.

Select the entity > Forms. Inside the Form editor window, open the **Form Properties** of the entity.

Go to **Display** Tab and untick "*Show navigation items*" checkbox.

Finally do not forget to Publish your changes.

Comment: but this one should be marked as the answer! you should avoid messing DOM up, except there's no other way to achive something

Comment: This is valid to hide all the navigation pane. Is there any other way to ide selected navigation section ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the relationshipname to hide folder in navigation like this:

If you have folder with the relationship name: `ts_inspection`

Use this for ID: `navts_inspection`

So otherwise the same as above, but lose the extra underscore (_) between `nav` and `ts`.

```
var navitem = Xrm.Page.ui.navigation.items.get("navts_inspection");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide particular navigation section from the FORM then remove all the links from that section and publish it. That section will not be visible anymore.

If you want to just remove Navigation Pane from FORM, then go to 'Display' tab of form and mark as 'Do Not Show' and then publish it.